# What options do I have for placing/installing a backflow preventer?

Tags: sprinkler-system

I'm installing a sprinkler system, and have to install a backflow preventer and pressure regulator at the start of the line.  What I don't like about this is having random bits of plumbing sticking out of my yard where they'll get hit by things, and look unsightly.  There is already a stub for irrigation water inside the house (in the basement) with a shutoff valve and a pipe going back outside.

Is there an indoor or underground option for backflow preventers?  Or do they have to stick out of the ground somewhere?  Do they have to be higher than any point in the line past them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, my (very) limited in-ground sprinkler system knowledge is pretty much documented here on SE:

- [How do I go about planning the layout of a sprinkler network for my lawn?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/how-do-i-go-about-planning-the-layout-of-a-sprinkler-network-for-my-lawn/1970#1970)

That said, as far as I'm aware there are certain types of "backflow preventers" that can be installed indoors or underground.

If you are able to use one of those devices (or are required to use some other kind of "backflow device") in your irrigation system, will "normally" come down to local building codes and/or local water company requirements. Therefore before installing any kind of "backflow device" it is recommend (required) that you check with those two local requirements before proceeding.

The below "backflow device" resources should prove helpful/useful:

- [Irrigation Backflow Preventers](http://www.irrigationtutorials.com/backflow-preventers.htm)
- [Irrigation Backflow Devices for lawn sprinkler and irrigation systems](http://www.sprinklerwarehouse.com/Irrigation-Backflow-Devices-s/21.htm)
- [Home Sprinkler Systems: Backflow Prevention Devices](http://www.ext.colostate.edu/pubs/crops/04714.html)

---

*Good luck! and please report back here with what kind of "backflow device" you end up having to use/install...*

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the recognized national standards and national model codes acknowledge irrigation sprinkler systems as a high hazard and require, as a minimum level of protection

- a [Reduced Pressure Principle backflow prevention assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_pressure_zone_device) or
- a [Pressure Vacuum Breaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_vacuum_breaker) or
- an [Atmospheric Vacuum Breaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_vacuum_breaker).