# What are the main kinds of permanent sprinklers and what they are best used for?

Tags: sprinkler-system

I have a lawn and a garden. That's about the extent to my expertise in keeping them tidy and healthy. I have some permanent sprinklers in some areas, but they downright stink, so I'd like to redo my whole property.

I have several lawned areas as big as 60' x 50' and as small as 20' x 30'. I also have some garden areas with what I hope to be vegetables one day, another with some dense lilac about 10' x 15', another with two large lilac trees, another area that I'd like to fill with flowers that runs the length of my driveway about 5' x 70', and one area with tulips and other bulb plants that gets lots of heat and sun because it's south facing and against the house about 5' x 25'.

In general, I'd like an overview of the main type of permanent sprinklers available and what they are best used for (or designed for) and for extra points which ones I should probably have on my lawn and in my gardens considered by plans and existing plants.

Comment: If you need more details I can do that. Also, I looked for like an [tag:overview] tag, but one does not exist that I know of. Sorry if this is off-topic.

Comment: I was really hoping for some activity on this question so I can get to work tomorrow.

Comment: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/how-do-i-go-about-planning-the-layout-of-a-sprinkler-network-for-my-lawn?rq=1

Comment: @Ecnerwal That will help some. Thank you.

Comment: This question is too braod and to thoroughly answer your question it would fill up an entire site. Luckily that site already exists. http://www.irrigationtutorials.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many different types of sprinklers, timers and control devices. It really depends on your budget, type of garden, climate, and how much control you want.

My personal preference?

black funny pipe shallowly buried and micro emitters\sprayers for shrubs, beds & fruit trees.

For lawns: Large diameter PVC deeply buried on lawn perimeters with steel risers in the corners and mid points and rain birds mounted high. I've never had great luck with popups.

If I could do mine over again I would build it like above described and an arduino based irrigation controller that can interface with a PC.

Good luck!